# Copy Access Query to Excel via VBA (error 3343)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm attempting to copy the results of an access query and paste it into an excel tab. I've googled around but can't seem to get it to work, I get the error "Error 3343: Unrecognized database format" so I assume it has something to do with the references I have checked.

Does anyone know the correct references I need to get this to work?

> References:
>
> Visual Basic For Application
>
> Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
>
> OLE Automation
>
> Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
>
> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
>
> Microsft DAO 3.6 Object Library

```
Sub Query()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim iCol As Integer

Sheets("DataDump1").Select
With Selection.ClearContents

End With
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Folder\DatabaseName.accdb")
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Query 1")

For iCol = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iCol) = rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
 Next iCol

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
db.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calling the Access Object before initializing the Database and Recordset objects. Also, use the [OpenCurrentDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837226.aspx) method as [OpenDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243164(v=office.12).aspx) is for the DBEngine Workspace object.

```
Sub Query()
    Dim accObj As Object
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim iCol As Integer

    Sheets("DataDump1").Cells.ClearContents

    Set accObj = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    accObj.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\Folder\DatabaseName.accdb")

    Set db = accObj.CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Query 1")

    For iCol = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Sheets("DataDump1").Cells(1, iCol) = rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
    Next iCol

    Sheets("DataDump1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    rst.Close
    db.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set accObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Alternatively, no need to interface with the Access object as Access is a database not just an .exe so can be connected via ODBC/OLEDB like any other RDMS (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)

```
Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim iCol As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Sheets("DataDump1").Cells.ClearContents

'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Folder\DatabaseName.accdb;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Folder\DatabaseName.accdb';"

    strSQL = " SELECT * FROM [Query 1];"

    ' OPEN DB AND RECORDSET
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For iCol = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Sheets("DataDump1").Cells(1, iCol) = rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
    Next iCol

    ' DATA ROWS
    Sheets("DataDump1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your second solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Great! And do note, second option does not need MSAccess.exe installed on the user's machine. Just have the .accdb file and a PC (which should have the Ace/Jet engine -Windows .dll files) installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think a references issue would give user defined type not recognised error. ADODB rather than DAO should work:

```
Sub Query()
Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim iCol As Integer

db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Folder\DatabaseName.accdb;"
rst.Open "Query 1", db

For iCol = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iCol) = rst.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
 Next iCol

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
db.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

EDIT: Please add latest microsoft activex data objects library as a reference for this to work